# Syntax error in IE11 with Webpack, Babel and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I'm getting a Syntax Error in my React + Redux project in Internet Explorer 11, but I have no idea why it's caused.

I'm using Webpack and Babel to compile it.

I tried using babel-polyfill and babel-es6-polyfill, but that didn't help.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: app.js, Line: 70, Column: 1
```

Line 70 Column 1 is where the `eval` starts of Webpack:

```
/***/ }),
/* 21 */,
/* 22 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\n\nObject.define... <- Line 70
^--- Column 1
```

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
'use strict';
// Include modules and plugins
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

// App and build directories
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/');
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');

// Extract sass from the application, see index.jsx
const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].css'
});

// The config file to load
let env = (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev').toLowerCase();
let configFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/config.' + env + '.json');

// Default config file if not found
const defaultConfigFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/config.dev.json');

/*
 * Config to be injected into the app
 * Note that JSON files are parsed upon requiring
 */
let config;

/*
 * Get the actual config
 */
try {
    config = require(configFile);
    console.log('Loaded config file ' + configFile);
} catch (e) {
    config = require(defaultConfigFile);
    console.log('Fallen back to default config file');
}

// The actual webpack config
const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
        // The app entry point
        app: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',

        // Vendor files will be used for bundling, they will not be compiled into the app itself
        vendor: [
            'axios',
            'prop-types',
            'react',
            'reactstrap',
            'react-chartjs-2',
            'react-dom',
            'react-redux',
            'react-router',
            'react-router-dom',
            'redux',
            'sprintf-js',
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'js/app.js'
    },

    module: {

        /*
         * These are loaders for webpack, these will assist with compilation
         */
        loaders: [
            {
                /*
                 * Use Babel to compile JS and JSX files
                 * See .babelrc
                 */
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                /*
                 * Sass/Scss compilation rules
                 */
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSass.extract({
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ],
                    fallback: 'style-loader'
                })
            },
            {
                /*
                 * JS(X) compilation rules
                 * We need this, otherwise Webpack will crash during compile time
                 */
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        /*
         * The CommonsChunkPlugin is responsible to create bundles out of commonly used modules
          * E.g. React, React Dom, etc
         */
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor', // See entry.vendor
            filename: 'js/vendor.bundle.js'
        }),
        extractSass
    ],
    externals: {
        /*
         * The config external will be available to the app by using require('config')
         */
        'config': JSON.stringify(config)
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
        compress: true,
        port: 7600,
        inline: true,
    },
};

if (env === 'production') {
    webpackConfig.devtool = 'hidden-source-map';
} else {
    webpackConfig.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

And my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.16.1",
  "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
  "babel-polyfill": "6.5.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
  "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
  "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
  "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
  "enumify": "^1.0.4",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
  "history": "^4.6.3",
  "ip": "^1.1.5",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "moment": "^2.18.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.5.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.5.2",
  "react-addons-transition-group": "^15.5.2",
  "react-chartjs-2": "^2.1.0",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-js-pagination": "^2.1.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
  "react-router": "^4.1.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
  "reactstrap": "^4.5.0",
  "redux": "^3.6.0",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
  "sprintf-js": "^1.1.0",
  "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
  "webpack": "^2.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1"
}
```

And my .babelrc:

```
{
   "presets" : [
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-1"
   ]
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Following BANANENMANNFRAU's answer, I added `babel-preset-env` and edited my `.babelrc` to be as follows:

```
{
   "presets" : [
      [ "env", {
         "targets": {
            "browsers": [
               "last 5 versions",
               "ie >= 11"
            ]
         }
      }],
      "es2015",
      "react",
      "stage-1"
   ]
}
```

This didn't help, it still resulted in the error in IE11.

Comment: Did you have any luck? I'm currently running into the same thing. I narrowed it down a little more by removing the source map, but babel-preset-env just doesn't seem to be including what it should.

Comment: Found solution in another topic
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372766/7801987

Answer (score 26):

I know it's over a year later, but I believe the issue was your devtool configuration:

```
webpackConfig.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
```

IE11 isn't a fan of the eval() code that gets inserted by webpack for those, apparently. Using `webpackConfig.devtool = 'none'` (or one of the [alternative values](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)) should fix it.

Comment: In my case , when I use eval-source-map it is working in IE11 along with target:es5. If I use ‘none’ it is not working. I don’t want to go with Evan-source-map as it is not recommended for production builds.

Answer (score 5):

Install [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env) with `npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev` and use the following config in your `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets" : [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
      }
    }],
    "react",
  ]
}
```

You can also remove the following part from your config:

```
        loaders: [
            {
                /*
                 * Use Babel to compile JS and JSX files
                 * See .babelrc
                 */
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ],
```

Check the docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work, same result. I had to exclude `babelrc: false`, because it wouldn't compile otherwise. I added my `.babelrc` to my post. Thanks for your post though.

Comment: Add the stuff your babelrc instead. That is crucial info.