# React, WebPack and Babel for Internet Explorer 10 and below produces SCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I've read multiple threads regarding similar issues and tried some propositions, but had no results.

I've followed few tutorials  related to **React.js** and **WebPack 3**. As the result the application is working well on all browsers (at this moment) except **IE 10** and below. The error points to bundle.js (once I'm using the configuration Nr.1):
`SCRIPT1002: Syntax error` and the line -  `const url = __webpack_require__(83);`

With configuration Nr2., on local server - : `SCRIPT1002: Syntax error` - line with `eval()`
And the same configuration, but running on remote server produces a bit different error:

`SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefine`

**WebPack configuration Nr1.:**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
})
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      }
    ],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,      
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
 },
   devServer: {   
      historyApiFallback: true,
      contentBase: './'
  },
 plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]
}
```

**WebPack configuration Nr2.:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const staticSourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'static');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname);
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    stats: {
        warnings: false
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
          devServer: {    
          historyApiFallback: true,
          contentBase: './'
      },
    entry: {
        app: path.resolve(sourcePath, 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack-loader.js', '.web-loader.js', '.loader.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: [
            sourcePath,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor',
            filename: 'vendor.[chunkhash].js',
            minChunks: Infinity
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer({
                        browsers: [
                            'last 3 version',
                            'ie >= 10'
                        ]
                    })
                ],
                context: staticSourcePath
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            path: buildPath,
            excludeChunks: ['base'],
            filename: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true
            }
        }),
        new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
            rel: 'preload',
            as: 'script',
            include: 'all',
            fileBlacklist: [/\.(css|map)$/, /base?.+/]
        }),
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            asset: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.eot?.+$|\.ttf?.+$|\.woff?.+$|\.svg?.+$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        })      
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: 'babel-loader',
                  options: {
                    presets: ['env', 'react', 'es2015'],
                    plugins: ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]
                  }
                },
                include: sourcePath
            },
            {                
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } },
                        'postcss-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot?.+|svg?.+|ttf?.+|otf?.+|woff?.+|woff2?.+)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    'url-loader?limit=20480&name=assets/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
                ],
                include: staticSourcePath
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Here additionally I've added the *es2015* to presets: `['env', 'react', 'es2015']` and `plugins: ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions"]` but it made no sense.

Well in case when the babel loader won't work at all of misconfiguration or something else, I think that the whole application won't start. I believe that something should be done with presets or their order... Need advice from experienced developer

**UPDATE**
I've changed devtool to `inline-cheap-module-source-map` and got error point to overlay.js -> `const ansiHTML = require('ansi-html');`

Comment: I've had success using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) and the `--ie8` option to make your code ie-proof.

Comment: hm.. I've added `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false,
                screw_ie8: true,
                conditionals: true,
                unused: true,
                comparisons: true,
                sequences: true,
                dead_code: true,
                evaluate: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true
            },output: { comments: false}
        }),` to config.. Well now error points to `(module,exports,__webpack_require__)`. I run this test locally - `npm start`

Comment: Can you add your *package.json* to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your *package.json* file

change the version of *webpack-dev-server* to version "2.7.1" (or earlier).

```
"webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1"
```

Then do a *npm install* et voilà.

That solved the problem for me.

All versions after 2.7.1 gives me an error similar to yours.

Comment: A had 2.9.1 version installed and  downgraded as you suggested and it now works on IE10. Only breaking in IE9 throwing `'set is undefine'`. So it's a **webpack-dev-server** bug?

Comment: Cool! I have no idea if it is a bug. I can advice you: Most tutorials are crap, people don't know what they are talking about or they are outdated. It is better to read the official Webpack documentation and tutorials. In your first config you use "loaders" AND '"rules", but loaders is for Webpack 1 and rules are for Webpack 2+ so strange mix that *will* cause problems.

Comment: For IE9 etc look up *babel-polyfill* in the babel documentation. So called polyfills will help old browsers in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `devtools : "source-map"` to your Webpack config like this:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.resolve(__dirname, './js/main.js')],
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: __dirname+'/js/',
    filename: 'main-webpack.js'
  }
};
```

This will remove `eval` and change your source map to be supported by  IE.

> UPDATE I've changed devtool to inline-cheap-module-source-map and got error point to overlay.js -> const ansiHTML = require('ansi-html');

And to support ES6 syntax you have to compile your JavaScript code with Babel.