# Angular4 and Webpack does not work on IE 11 (Edge)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, webpack

The title is clear already that I have setup a project using angular4 with webpack.

It runs well on Chrome, but when I test it on IE 11, it does not show anything (aside from favicon and web title).

One error is there:
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
File: vendor.bundle.js

It points to the eval() function in the bundle js.

I tried everything from adding shims, change target to ES5/ES6, and uncomment the necessary imports in the polyfills.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of ecmascript are you targeting in your tsconfig? es5 or es6? edit:nvm - I see that you have tried changing it. Have you tried clearing your cache after you change those settings?

Comment: Yes, I made sure of it,@Daryl and Just for info, I cannot use es6 because when I changed it to ES6, it will be error in Chrome as well, module is ES2015

Comment: I just created a new angular CLI project and uncommented the required polyfills for IE 9 10 and 11 in polyfills.ts. Seems to work for me... Just for a sanity check do the same and see if it works for you with minimal changes to the configuration.

Comment: I gave an answer in another topic
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372766/7801987

Comment: Hi @EldonLesley, I have the same issue , on loading the Angular4 app in iE11 , I get error SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error vendor.bundle.js(8315,1), and the line has eval function, please let me know if you have any solution