# Vue.js and Internet Explorer Compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, vuejs2

I’m trying to make works my vuejs app in Internet explorer, I see the polyfill issue in google so I add this at the top of my main.js :

```
import Promise from 'es6-promise';

Promise.polyfill();

/* eslint-disable import/first */
```

But I still have a blank page and in developper tools I have this error :
[image]
(in French, “attendu” means “expected”)

When I open the app.js via IE the line 9836 refer to this :
[image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: You're asking the wrong questions. This has nothing to do with Vue, it's a webpack issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error in IE11 with Webpack, Babel and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212267/syntax-error-in-ie11-with-webpack-babel-and-react)